# How to calculate total from three components in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

So, let explain to me what I am trying to achieve I am having a component called `RoomDetails` which has child components called `SelectRoomDetails`(In picture its Superior Room, Deluxe Room, Place 3 child components). On selection of rooms, `price` will be calculated and on the selection of tax, it will get calculated as shown in the picture.

On selection of room `SelectRoomDetails` will `emit` an event called `total-price` where I am passing `price` and `tax`. And I am catching that `total-price` event in `RoomDetails` and But the problem is I am not able to figure out how to calculate `Sum` and `price` is coming from three child components in this case.

My question is how can I write `calculateTotalPrice` method so it calculates `Sum` on the selection of room and minus it on deselection of room. Thanks in advance!

**SelectRoomDetails.vue**

```
totalPrice(base_price) {
      if(this.selected.length > 0) {
           let price = base_price*this.selected.length;
            let startDate = moment(this.guestCheckIn, "DD.MM.YYYY");
            let endDate = moment(this.guestCheckOut, "DD.MM.YYYY");

            let result = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
            let days = parseInt(result);
            this.roomtype_net_price = price*days;     
            let tax = this.taxes.find(taxes => taxes.id == this.selectedTax);     
            if(tax)
            {
                let newPrice = this.getTax(tax, this.roomtype_net_price);
                console.log(newPrice);
                this.taxPrice = newPrice;
            }
            else
            {
              this.taxPrice = 0;
            }
           }
          else
          {
            this.roomtype_net_price = 0
          }
            this.$emit("total-price", this.roomtype_net_price, this.taxPrice);      
          },
            changePrice(price) {
            this.roomType.base_price = price
            this.totalPrice(price);   
          }
```

**RoomDetails.vue**

```
<tr v-for="roomType in roomTypes" :key="roomType.id">
        <select-room-details
          :room-type="roomType"
          :taxes="taxes"
          :guest-check-in="guestCheckIn"
          :guest-check-out="guestCheckOut"
          v-on:select-room="selectRoom"
          v-on:total-price="calculateTotalPrice"
        ></select-room-details>
      </tr>
```

**Method in RoomDetails.vue**

```
 calculateTotalPrice(total, tax) {
      this.totalPrice = 0;
      this.totalTax = tax;
      this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + total + tax;
    }
  }
```

**Sum is displayed here**

```
  <td class="display-2">Sum: {{this.totalPrice}}</td>
```

[image]

Comment: If you ask the question, "how do I get data from child components", the answer is usually that the ownership of the data should be moved up to the parent and read-only values should be passed down to the child. The parent is the source of truth for the data, and the child emits events when it wants to make a change to the data.

Comment: Here, in this case, the child is emitting an `event` every time there is a change in price but I am not able to figure out how to add. For example when I select room in `superior room` component  `this.totalPrice = 999;` but when I again select a room in `Deluxe Room`  component `this.totalPrice = 0;` so the `Sum` becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to have each room emit an event with its price and tack on the room id (or some other unique value)

```html
<tr 
    v-for="roomType in roomTypes"
    :key="roomType.id"
>
    <select-room-details
      v-on:total-price="roomPriceUpdated(roomType.id, $event)"
    />
</tr>
```

And store that in `data` with a `computed` value that sums the prices.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      roomPrices: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onRoomPriceUpdated(roomId, price) {
        this.roomPrices[roomId] = price;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalPrice() {
        return Object.values(this.roomPrices)
            .reduce((roomPrice, totalPrice) => roomPrice + totalPrice, 0);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The sum should now be available as `this.totalPrice` within the component.